# Why is the output of this C program 64 and not 320?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 320;
    char *ptr;

    ptr = (char *)&a;
    printf("%d", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be `320` but instead I'm getting `64`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Why did you expect 320?

Comment: @melpomene Since ptr is getting dereferenced

Comment: Yeah, but `*ptr` has type `char`. How are you going to fit 320 into a single `char`?

Answer (score 9):

If your system's `CHAR_BIT` is 8 (probably the case) then you get at most 8 bits in a dereferenced `char *` pointer.  In binary, the value `320` is `0b000101000000`.

It would appear that your system is using little-endian byte order; the least significant 8 bits of 320 are `0b01000000`, which is 64 in base 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
320 = 0b101000000
0b0100000  = 64
```

you are using a char pointer, you should use a int pointer, `ptr = (char *)&a;`